# Where can I pass the value of percentage of request on each http request in jmeter?

Tags: apache, jmeter, performance-testing

I am testing load in jmeter. Now I have 8-10 page requests to be execute. But I want to provide percentage/number of request in this page and another page is having difference number of request.

eg.

1. home page should have 30% of request
2. details page should have 10% of request

....

How can I do this using jmeter ?
Please Advice me.

Comment: Any feedback on this, was answer ok , if yes you should accept it so that it helps others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have say 10 pages to be tested inside a single thread group, and you have percentage of requests to be sent to some pages such that:

home page 30%
details page 10%
...

then you may make multiple HTTP Requests to a same page inside a thread group.

For example if you have two pages say home and details and you want 75% requests on home and 25% to detail, then you may make three HTTP requests to home and one to details page inside the thread group.

**EDIT:** May be this structure be suitable for your scenario:

```
+ Thread Group 
|+ Loop Controller 
|-+ If Controller (Random Value < 90) 
|--+ Sampler1 
|--+ Sampler2 
|--+ ... 
|-+ If Controller (Random Value >= 90) 
|--+ Sampler10 
|--+ ...
```

or this

```
+ Thread group 
|+ Loop Controller 
|-+ Sampler1 
|-+ Sampler2 
|-+ ... 
|-+ Throughput Controller (e.g. 90 per minute) 
+ Thread group 
|+ Loop Controller 
|-+ Sampler10 
|-+ Sampler11 
|-+ ... 
--+ Throughput Controller (e.g. 10 per minute)
```

I found these here: [here](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/How-throughput-controller-work-td3328412.html)

Comment: Thanks , but for larger test this idea is not suitable for me. Is there any way to do this for a larger test ???

Comment: @KrutalModi What do you mean by larger test?

Comment: I have 8-10 page request for a long time with distributed percentage of requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) with the following setting:

[image]

You may have to check Per User depending on what you need.

Use [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) listener to check the percentage.

Another option is described here:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_control_percentage_of_sampler/